# All analytic functions whose real part is analytic in the unit disk .

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all analytic functions whose real part is analytic in the unit disk .

I don't know from where i should start ?

My Guess is that $f(z) = c $

Thank you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is a non constant and analytic on some open $A$, then $f(U)$ is open
for any open $U \subset A$.

It follows that if the real part is analytic, then it is constant, say $x_0$.

Then $z \mapsto i (f(z) -x_0)$ is analytic and hence the imaginary part of $f$ is constant.

Hence $f$ is constant.